# Trying to pass by value in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, copy

i'm encountering avery strange issue when programming in python 3.7:

```
A = [[1,2],[0,3]]
B = A[:][:]   # creates a copy of A to work with, without modify A
del B[0]
```

This works,well,as B becomes [[0,3]] and A is still [[1,2],[0,3]].
However, if I try this :

```
A = [[1,2],[0,3]]
B = A[:][:]     # creates a copy of A to work with, without modify A
del B[0][1]
```

B becomes `[[1], [0, 3]]`, but A also turns into `[[1], [0, 3]]` !
I can't understand this behaviour,could you explain me what's happening there ?

Comment: `B = A[:][:]` is the same thing as `B = A[:]`. To copy multiple levels of lists, use [copy.deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy).

Comment: Thanks,copy.deepcopy worked perfectly !